# Called directive method when directive is shown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive which displays a canvas on screen which you can then draw on. I have code in my controller to show/hide the canvas.

```
<canvas class="gate-canvas" id="canvas" ng-show="showGateCanvas" gate></canvas>

<button ng-click="showCanvas()">Draw</button>
```

And in my controller:

```
$scope.showCanvas = function() {

    //doing some other stuff

    $scope.showGateCanvas = true;
}
```

The canvas then dislpays on screen and the user can draw on it. The problem is when the user clicks another button to remove the canvas, then clicks the 'Draw' button to show it again, the canvas still has their last drawing. I want it cleared.

I have a method called `reset()` in the directive which clears it. How can I call this as soon as a user clicks 'Draw' and the canvas directive is shown?

Comment: create the **reset()** method in your controller. In the event listener of **another button to remove the canvas**. you can call the reset function.

Answer (score 0):

You can create "Reset" method inside "link" of directive. It can be called if you have not override $scope inside directive.

Answer (score 0):

```
<canvas class="gate-canvas" id="canvas" ng-if="showGateCanvas" gate></canvas>

<button ng-click="showCanvas()">Draw</button>
```

Change ng-show/hide to ng-if as
ng-show/hide will have elements on dom and just hidden/shown,
but ng-if will remove the element from dom and when you show it again, directive will be initiated again.

Also `keeping` reset method in directive scope and whenever directive is being shown you can invoke that function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-if` rather than `ng-show`,

But if you don't, update your `directive`:

```
link:function(scope,element,attrs){
    scope.$watch(function() { return element.is(':visible') },function(){
        //call your reset here
    });

    //other things...
}
```